# Área de cadastro de clientes em WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Existe algum *plugin* que faça cadastro de clientes para o **wordpress**?

Preciso de uma área separada da área de login onde clientes possam se cadastrar para receber arquivos e afins.

**Obs.:** preciso que esses clientes tenham seu cadastro a parte dos usuários com acesso ao painel administrativo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o https://wordpress.org/plugins/customer-area/

Sempre foi muito útil em alguns projetos que precisei.